# How to pass Retrofit onResponse Data to an Activity?

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, adapter, retrofit2

I want to pass retrofit response to Activity so that i can set data in the recyclerview adapter. I don't want to use LiveData or RxJava.
Here imageDetails is the list of Json Object and I want to pass it to MainActivity.

**TrendingViewModel.kt**

```
class TrendingViewModel : ViewModel() {

fun fetchGifs() {
    val apiService = GiphyApi().getClient()?.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    val call = apiService?.getTrendingResults(20, Constants.API_KEY)
    var imageDetails: List<ImageDetails>


    call?.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<GiphyResponse> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<GiphyResponse>?, response: Response<GiphyResponse>?) {
            imageDetails = response?.body()?.data!!
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<GiphyResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
        }
    })
}}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
lateinit var adapter: RecyclerViewAdapter
lateinit var trendingViewModel: TrendingViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    val debugTree: Timber.DebugTree = Timber.DebugTree()
    TrendingViewModel().fetchGifs()
    Timber.plant(debugTree)

    trendingViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TrendingViewModel::class.java)
    trendingViewModel.fetchGifs()
    layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3) as RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    binding.recyclerview.layoutManager = layoutManager
    adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(this)
    binding.recyclerview.adapter = adapter
    adapter.setListData(//TODO I need the response data here)

}}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.kt**

Edit: Everthing is working fine but My list is getting updated after all the default function is called.

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(){


private var gifList: List<ImageDetails>? = Collections.emptyList()
private var mContext: Context? = null

init {
    this.mContext = context
}

fun setListData(list: List<ImageDetails>) {
    gifList=list
    Log.i("Size SetListData", gifList!!.size.toString())

    //Here it is showing List size 20
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder? {
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<RecyclerviewListItemBinding>(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), R.layout.recyclerview_list_item,
            parent, false)

    return ViewHolder(binding)

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    //val binding = holder.binding;
    Log.i("Size SizeBindHolder",gifList?.size.toString())

    //Size = 0

    /*Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(gifList?.get(position)?.images?.dimen?.url)
            .into(holder.imageView)*/

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    Log.i("Size ItemCount",gifList?.size.toString())
    // Size = 0 
    return gifList?.size!!
}




class ViewHolder(var binding: RecyclerviewListItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    var imageView: ImageView

    init {
        this.binding = binding
        imageView = binding.imageView
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a function to update data in adapter. Call it in response. And call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Could you please elaborate ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pass your desired method which needs to be called as functional parameter, try below here **fetchGifs** accepts one method as parameter & in  **MainActivity** we are passing **adapter.setListData** to it as parameter

```
class TrendingViewModel : ViewModel() {

fun fetchGifs(callback: (giphyResponse: GiphyResponse) -> Any) {
    val apiService = GiphyApi().getClient()?.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    val call = apiService?.getTrendingResults(20, Constants.API_KEY)
    var imageDetails: List<ImageDetails>


    call?.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<GiphyResponse> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<GiphyResponse>?, response: Response<GiphyResponse>?) {
            imageDetails = response?.body()?.data!!
            callback(imageDetails) 
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<GiphyResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
        }
    })
}}




class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
lateinit var adapter: RecyclerViewAdapter
lateinit var trendingViewModel: TrendingViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    val debugTree: Timber.DebugTree = Timber.DebugTree()
    Timber.plant(debugTree)

    trendingViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TrendingViewModel::class.java)
    trendingViewModel.fetchGifs()
    layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3) as RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    binding.recyclerview.layoutManager = layoutManager
    adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(this)
    binding.recyclerview.adapter = adapter
    TrendingViewModel().fetchGifs(result -> adapter.setListData(result))


}}
```

Comment: Hey @Akhil It is working like a charm, thank you man. But I have a question  I'm getting complete list in the adapter but not able to get size in getItemCount() method. How do I do it ?

Comment: In setListData you should update your list data  & in getItemCount should return size of updated list

Comment: I have updated the list from setListData but this method is called after the all the overriden methods so list is updating after all the default recyclerview methods gets called.

Comment: If there are no items in list return 0 else return the size of the updated list, this method will be called by recycleView multiple times, it's all asynchronous

Comment: Used notifyDataSetChanged() ... It's working now.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1- in your activity add:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Observer { 
        ....
    }
```

2- implement the method `update()` in your `activity`:

```
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {


    }
```

3- create an Observable object:

```
public class RetrofitObservable extends Observable {

    private static RetrofitObservable instance = null;

    public static RetrofitObservable getInstance() {

         if(instance == null) {

             instance = new RetrofitObservable();

         }

         return instance;
    }

    public void notifyObserverWithResponse(Object response) {

        setChanged();

        notifyObservers(response);

    }

}
```

4- in your activity `onResume()` add this line:

```
RetrofitObservable.getInstance().addObserver(this);
```

5- in your activity `onPause()` add this line:

```
RetrofitObservable.getInstance().deleteObserver(this);
```

6- in your Retrofit response, call this line:

```
RetrofitObservable.getInstance(). notifyObserverWithResponse(yourResponseHere);
```

7- in your activity `update` method, handle your response:

```
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

    YourRetrofitResponse response = (YourRetrofitResponse) arg;

    // make your changes here

}
```

Comment: Hey Man Thank you for the reply, although I haven't tried yet because I found @Akhil's answer easier. Anyway Thank you.